# How to divide (1*3) vector by a (3*3) matrix using Numpy? a/b does not work

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, vector

```
a = np.array([[0.1562,0.0774,0.0702]])
b = np.array([
[0.0365,0.0191,0.0217],
[0.0191,0.0331,0.0292],
[0.0217,0.0292,0.0591]])
```

The output in MATLAB (**desired output**) is:

```
 4.4911    0.2724   -0.5958
```

The output I get in Python is:

```
4.27945205 4.05235602 3.23502304
8.17801047 2.33836858 2.40410959
7.19815668 2.65068493 1.18781726
```

The code I am using in Python is:

```
a/b
```

I have also tried `np.divide(a,b)` but they all give the same output which is not what I want. Is it something with '/' vs './' in MATLAB

What should my code in Python be to obtain the same output as in MATLAB?

Comment: Matrix division doesn’t exist. In MATLAB, the matrix division operator is really a linear equation solver. The equation AB=C can be solved for A in MATLAB by writing `A=C/B`. In Python you likely need to look for a function that solves linear systems of equations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi, do you mean C = A/B?

Comment: @Anonymous, `a` has shape (1, 3), and you refer to an array with shape (3, 3), but the  `b` that you show has shape `(5, 5)`.  Can you show the actual 3x3 matrix that you used?

Comment: @Anonymous hey, thanks for the headsup, its (3,3) for the matrix. So it's (1,3) / (3,3)

Comment: You can use `np.linalg.solve(b.T, a.T)`

Comment: Yes, the `numpy` `/` is element-wise, like the MATLAB `./`  (same for other operators like `.*` and `.+`).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this system with **numpy.linalg.lstsq**

```
import numpy as np
    
a = np.array([[0.1562,0.0774,0.0702]])
b = np.array([
        [0.0365,0.0191,0.0217],
        [0.0191,0.0331,0.0292],
        [0.0217,0.0292,0.0591]])
        
        
x = np.linalg.lstsq(b.T,a.T)
print(x)

Result:

(array([[ 4.49111376],
       [ 0.2724206 ],
       [-0.59580119]]), array([], dtype=float64), 3, array([0.09268238, 0.02342602, 0.0125916 ]))
```

As pointed out by @WarrenWeckesser, for this problem, **np.linalg.solve** will also work, similar syntax to above